# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Java Exception

Tags: java, exception, memory-leaks

Why am I getting this error? I don't understand.. Here's the code where it throws the exception

```
  public static final int getItemDefinitionsSize(Store store) {
    int lastArchiveId = store.getIndexes()[19].getLastArchiveId();
    return lastArchiveId * 256
            + store.getIndexes()[19].getValidFilesCount(lastArchiveId);
}
```

And here is the exception itself.

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
    at com.alex.Utils.getItemDefinitionsSize(Utils.java:50)
    at Kjs.Application.addAllItems(Application.java:186)
    at Kjs.Application.initialize(Application.java:182)
    at Kjs.Application.<init>(Application.java:52)
    at Kjs.Application$1.run(Application.java:39)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
    ce)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I think your exception is pretty self explanatory, you are referencing an index that isn't in your array.

Comment: Well it isn't my code... Its something someone else wrote, that before now worked perfectly. I have no idea how it the index isn't in the array..

Comment: Then you should investigate what the data looks like. Use a debugger to examine it.

Comment: @Keppil says do some research/debugging before posting the question

Comment: @David, what have you tried? You haven't given us any more information that might let us help you. What code leads into the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below line

```
int lastArchiveId = store.getIndexes()[19].getLastArchiveId();
```

you are trying to get value from there which does not exists.That means the length of that array you are accessing is below 19.

But you have to do your homework before posting here.